# Help with used unused space on disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, trash

Here is the problem, i tried to install phoenix os by this tutorial: https://www.fosslicious.com/2018/07/how-to-install-phoenix-os-on-ubuntu-linux.html 
and so i created a 30gb .img in /phoenix folder
later i decided to delete it, so i deleted the /phoenix folder by moving to trash can and then empty the trash can. The problem is that in Disks they say me that my Ubuntu partition has that 30gb in use. ¿How can i free this space?
(sorry my bad english please)

Comment: You lack permission to delete files that you don't own.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my self.
started nautilus as root and shift-deleted the .local trash folder.

im still newbie in ubuntu